# std::lenght_error when parsing json

Tags: c++, json, libcurl

EDIT: I tried even store the result in a file and parse from the file content but isn't working either... same error...

```
if (httpCode == 200)
    {
        // Response looks good - done using Curl now.  Try to parse the results
        // and print them out.
        Json::Value jsonData;
        Json::Reader jsonReader;

        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("C:\\Users\\ingfr\\source\\repos\\Cheat1\\Debug\\example.txt");
        myfile << *httpData.get();
        myfile.close();

        string line;
        ifstream myfile2("C:\\Users\\ingfr\\source\\repos\\Cheat1\\Debug\\example.txt");
        if (myfile2.is_open()) { // always check whether the file is open
            myfile2 >> line; // pipe file's content into stream
        }





            if (jsonReader.parse(line, jsonData))
            {
                return jsonData["error"].asString();
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Could not parse HTTP data as JSON" << std::endl;
            }
        
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Couldn't GET from " << url << " - exiting" << std::endl;
    }
```

i'm trying to make my c++ application able to store username and password given by user (the password will be encoded in base64) and then try to use curl ans jsonhpp to get the json response from my website api. It has $_GET, so it will be like this: `https://example.com/api.php?key=5746732&user=username&pass=base64_password`

I tried to use curl with json parsing and curl but it throw an error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x77C13572 in Cheat1.exe: Microsoft C ++ exception: std :: length_error at memory location 0x006FF950.
```

I tried to do some debugging and it stop at when the software try to parse the data (`if (jsonReader.parse(*httpData.get(), jsonData))`).

The json result on the api looks like this:

```
{"status":"success","uid":"1","username":"Yacker","hwid":null,"admin":"1","sub":"2021-10-25","banned":"0","invitedBy":"admin","createdAt":"2021-09-10 12:12:46"} (when account found)


{"status":"failed","error":"Invalid username"} (When username or password are wrong)
```

The full code is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <json/json.h>
#include "base64.h";


namespace
{
    std::size_t callback(
        const char* in,
        std::size_t size,
        std::size_t num,
        std::string* out)
    {
        const std::size_t totalBytes(size * num);
        out->append(in, totalBytes);
        return totalBytes;
    }
}

std::string result_json(std::string type,std::string username,std::string password_h,std::string hwid)
{
    const std::string url("https://example.com/api.php?key=5746732&user=" + username + "&pass="+ password_h);

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    // Set remote URL.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

    // Don't bother trying IPv6, which would increase DNS resolution time.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

    // Don't wait forever, time out after 10 seconds.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Follow HTTP redirects if necessary.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    // Response information.
    long httpCode(0);


    std::unique_ptr<std::string> httpData(new std::string());


    // Hook up data handling function.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);

    // Hook up data container (will be passed as the last parameter to the
    // callback handling function).  Can be any pointer type, since it will
    // internally be passed as a void pointer.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, httpData.get());

    // Run our HTTP GET command, capture the HTTP response code, and clean up.
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpCode);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    if (httpCode == 200)
    {
        // Response looks good - done using Curl now.  Try to parse the results
        // and print them out.
        Json::Value jsonData;
        Json::Reader jsonReader;


        try
        {
            if (jsonReader.parse(*httpData.get(), jsonData))
            {
                if (jsonData["status"].asString() == "failed")
                {
                  return jsonData["error"].asString();
                }
                else
                {
                    return jsonData[type].asString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Could not parse HTTP data as JSON" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        catch (std::length_error &ex)
        {

        }
        
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Couldn't GET from " << url << " - exiting" << std::endl;
    }
}






int main()
{
    //login prompt
    std::string username;
    std::string password;






    std::cout << "Username: ";
    std::cin >> username;

    std::cout << "Password: ";
    std::cin >> password;

    std::string password_base64 = base64_encode(password, false);
    std::cout << result_json("username", username, password_base64, "i23");

}
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` expects long value, you pass int.

Comment: @S.M. I don't udnerstand.. CURLOPT_TIMEOUT is for waiting timeout and espects an int not a long value...

Comment: Read the manual carefully.

Comment: @S.M. I tried with `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10L);` but same error

Comment: Look at `*httpData.get()` std::string value in the debugger. Does it look to be valid?

Comment: @S.M. The httpData.get() value is: 010D8C68, the *httpData.get() value is: ""

Comment: you should probably be checking the result of `curl_easy_perform`

Comment: @AlanBirtles What do you mean?

Comment: `curl_easy_perform` (and all the other curl functions) return a value to indicate success or an error you should check what that value is

Comment: @AlanBirtles it says "true (204)" but when it go to "curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpCode);" it becomes false

Comment: 204 usually indicates an uninitialised variable

Comment: Yeah and how to fix? I picked this from a github file (json and curl). Like i don't wanna full code fixed because of the rules.  I wanna get some ideas of how to fix @AlanBirtles

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69332360/edit) your question to show how you're reading the result of `curl_easy_perform`. Split your problem into 2 parts, 1. does downloading the JSON work, save the json to a file. 2. read the JSON from the file and parse it, this should help you narrow down where your problem lies (or just use a debugger to find where and why the exception happens)

Comment: If you get the same error reading from a file then your question can be greatly simplified by removing all the curl code and just showing the file contents and the JSON parsing

Comment: e.g. a [mre] might look something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/6Kcccn6zj) (though that works correctly and doesn't throw an exception)

Comment: @AlanBirtles The example you send (https://godbolt.org/z/6Kcccn6zj) is throwing same error.....

Comment: I guess you have a buggy/misconfigured version of JSONCPP in that case

Answer (score 0):

Well, i fixed using another json library.

parser.h:

```
#ifndef PARSER_H
#define PARSER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <json/json.h>
#include <json/reader.h>
#include <json/writer.h>
#include <json/value.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

class Parser {
public:
    Parser(const std::string& s) : url(s) {}
    Parser() {}
    void request();
    std::string get_json_string();
    std::string username;
    std::string password_h;
    std::string hwid;
    Json::Value get_json() { return root; }
    std::string json_value;
private:
    std::string url;
    Json::Value root;

    static std::size_t write_callback(char* in, std::size_t size, std::size_t nmemb, std::string* out);
};

std::string Parser::get_json_string() {
    Json::FastWriter fastWriter;
    return fastWriter.write(root);
}

std::size_t Parser::write_callback(char* in, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string* out) {
    std::size_t total_size = size * nmemb;
    if (total_size) {
        out->append(in, total_size);
        return total_size;
    }
    return 0; 
}
void Parser::request() {
    // Parse raw Json string
    std::string str_buffer;
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        CURLcode res;

        std::string url1 = "https://example.com/api.php?key=148H1329F2H982&user=" + username + "&pass=" + Parser::password_h + "&hwid=" + hwid;

        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url1.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &str_buffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        json_value = str_buffer;
        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            std::cerr << "curl_easy_perform() failed:" << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Could not initialize curl" << std::endl;
    }

    //// Convert string to Json::Value
    //Json::Reader reader;
    //bool parse_status = reader.parse(str_buffer.c_str(), root);
    //if (!parse_status) {
    //    std::cout << "parse() failed: " << reader.getFormattedErrorMessages() << std::endl;
    //    return;
    //}
}
#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include "base64.h";
#include <fstream>
#include "parser.h"
#include <json/nlohmann/json.hpp>
using namespace std;
using nlohmann::json;

namespace
{
    std::size_t callback(
        const char* in,
        std::size_t size,
        std::size_t num,
        std::string* out)
    {
        const std::size_t totalBytes(size * num);
        out->append(in, totalBytes);
        return totalBytes;
    }
}

std::string result_json(std::string type,std::string username,std::string password_h,std::string hwid)
{
    Parser jsonp;
    jsonp.username = username;
    jsonp.password_h = password_h;
    jsonp.hwid = hwid;

    jsonp.request();
    return jsonp.json_value;
}






int main()
{
    //login prompt
    std::string username;
    std::string password;

    HANDLE  hConsole;
    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 9);


    std::cout << "|| RAINY";


    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 3);

    std::cout << "CHEATS ||" << std::endl << std::endl;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 15);








    std::cout << "Username: ";
    std::cin >> username;

    std::cout << "Password: ";
    std::cin >> password;

    std::string password_base64 = base64_encode(password, false);

    json myjson = json::parse(result_json("username", username, password_base64, "i23"));

    std::cout << myjson["error"];
    //result_json("username", username, password_base64, "i23");;

   
}
```